Can you authenticate to ghcr.io and pull down images using fine-grained access tokens?
I want to pull down an image on the GitHub Container Registry. It requires authentication? Can I use a fine-grained access PAT for that?

No
Not currently anyway. There is a ticket for this #558
This is also mentioned in Working with the Container registry: "Authenticating to the Container registry"

GitHub Packages only supports authentication using a personal access token (classic). For more information, see "Managing your personal access tokens."

